# Grid column size calculation

Tags: css, sass

I have a one function to calculate all the possible `widths` plus the `margins` for the gutters.

In this same function, the grid extensions such as the `pull`, `push`and `offset` functions are also calculated.

```
@function calculate-one-column() {
  $a: 100%;
  @if ($gutter-width-px > 0px) {
    $a: ($a - ($gutter-width-procent * ($column-count - 1)));
  }
  @return $a / $column-count;
}

@function calculate-each-gutter() {
  @if ($gutter-width-px > 0px) {
    @return $gutter-width-procent;
  }
  @return 0;
}

@function calculate-function($function, $size, $first-child: false, $responsive: false) {
  $each-column: calculate-one-column() * $size;
  $each-gutter: calculate-each-gutter() * ($size - 1);
  @if ($function == 'size') {
    @return $each-column + $each-gutter;

  } @else if ($function == 'offset' and $first-child == false) and ($responsive == false) {
    @return $each-column + $each-gutter + ($gutter-width-procent * 1.5);

  } @else if ($function == 'push' or $function == 'pull') and ($responsive == false) or ($function == 'offset' and $first-child == true) {
    @return $each-column + $each-gutter + $gutter-width-procent;

  } @else if($function == 'offset' or 'push' or 'pull') and ($responsive == true)  {
    @return auto !important;
  }
}
```

The `calculate-function` `@function` is getting called by this piece of code:

```
@mixin make-grid-sizes() {
  @for $index from 1 through $column-count {
    &.#{$column-size}#{$index} {
      @include calculate-property('width', $index);
    }
  }
}
```

All of these functions are getting hold together with these variables:

```
$column-count: 12;
$row-max-width: 1024px;

$gutter-width-px: 15px !default;
$gutter-width-procent: percentage($gutter-width-px / $row-max-width);
```

The code works perfectly, but in my opinion it looks very messy.

Comment: How is this different from your previous question?  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52360/sass-grid-system-improvements

Comment: @cimmanon I thought: this one is about the calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning: I am far from an expert with Sass!

I'll list a few things I think could use some re-factoring.

---

We can DRY out your code. In the main function, I see `$each-column + $each-gutter` three times. Create a variable and assign the variable the sum.

---

This line: `if ($function == 'offset' and $first-child == false) and ($responsive == false)` can all be in one pair of parentheses. Breaking it apart actually reduces clarity.

---

I find that this line:

```
if ($function == 'push' or $function == 'pull') and ($responsive == false) or ($function == 'offset' and $first-child == true)
```

is difficult to read. Note my changes in the code below.

---

A couple instances, things seem mistaken. For example, this line:

```
if ($function == 'offset' or 'push' or 'pull')
```

doesn't seem to be correct. I tried to copy this conditional, and I'm surprised you haven't noticed the error.

This statement says: *If `$function` is equal to 'offset', or either 'push' is non-null or 'pull' is non-null*. I believe it should be:

```
if ($function == 'offset' or $function == 'push' or $function == 'pull') and ($responsive == true) {
```

---

I've written your code to take into account all of these modifications. I think it looks neater, however it's not meant to be completely superficial. Since my Sass isn't very strong I hope someone else will be able to help break down your code with you more thoroughly.

```
@function calculate-function($function, $size, $first-child: false, $responsive: false) {
    $each-column: calculate-one-column() * $size;
    $each-gutter: calculate-each-gutter() * ($size - 1);

    $sum-width: $each-column + $each-gutter;

    $push-or-pull: ($function == 'push' or $function == 'pull');
    $offsetting: $function == 'offset';

    @if ($function == 'size') {
        @return $sum-width;

    } @else if ($offsetting and $first-child == false and $responsive == false) {
        @return $sum-width + ($gutter-width-percent * 1.5);

    } @else if $push-or-pull and ($responsive == false) or ($offsetting and $first-child) {
        @return $sum-width + $gutter-width-percent;

    } @else if ($offsetting or $push-or-pull) and $responsive {
        @return auto !important;
    }
}
```

Also, you misspelled *percent* as *procent*. I suggest you change that in all occurrences.